# multiple definition of class

Tags: c++, class, definition

first of all I know that this question has been answered very often, but the answers didn't help me a lot...

That is the code which is causing the error.

```
#include "WayFinderClass.h"
WayFinderClass::WayFinderClass(int NavigationMapIndex) { ... };
int WayFinderClass::TotalNumberOfPoints(int point[100][100][2]) { ... };
int WayFinderClass::ConnectedWithXPoints(int point[100][100][2], int pointID) { ... };
void WayFinderClass::findWay(int start, int goal) { ... };
```

WayFinderClass.h :

```
#ifndef WAYFINDERCLASS_H_INCLUDED
#define WAYFINDERCLASS_H_INCLUDED
#include "NavigationMap.h"

class WayFinderClass {
    public:
        int finalWay[100];
        int start;
        int goal;
        int alreadyCheckedInt[100];
        void findWay(int start, int goal);
        WayFinderClass(int NavigationMapIndex);
    private:
        int pointConnectedWith[100];
        int wayProgress[100][100];
        int numberOfPoints;
        bool antsInProgress[100];
        int TotalNumberOfPoints(int point[100][100][2]);
        int ConnectedWithXPoints(int point[100][100][2], int pointID);
        NewNavigationMap NavigationMap;
};

#endif // WAYFINDER_H_INCLUDED
```

And that is the error I get:

```
C:\{...} Line 3 multiple definition of 'WayFinderClass::WayFinderClass(int)'
```

So what am I supposed to do? I already tried to include the .h file but it didn't help me.
I also checked every other file whether the file WayFinderClass.cpp has been included a second time - but I found nothing.

Comment: Are you getting the error in `WayFinderClass.cpp`?

Comment: Yes I do... The error is caused in the line I wrote at first (WayFinderClass::etc.)

Comment: First of all make you constructor `explicit` (e.g., `explicit WayFinderClass(int NavigationMapIndex);`). Secondly, it looks OK to me.

Comment: What is in NavigationMap.h?  Have you tried to temporarily remove this include and the dependent code to see if it will build without it?

Comment: That doesn't work either.

Comment: Can you post a summary of the other definitions in your cpp class?  You don't need to post their content, just post the basic structure.

Comment: If I remove the include of NavigationMap.h it doesn't work either.
The code of NavigationMap.h is:

#ifndef NAVIGATIONMAP_H_INCLUDED
#define NAVIGATIONMAP_H_INCLUDED

class NewNavigationMap {
public:
    int point[100][100][2];
    void createMap_1();
};

#endif // NAVIGATIONMAP_H_INCLUDED

Comment: Would you happen to include `WayFinderClass.cpp` in any file?

Comment: I edited my question so you can see the whole document.
And no I included WayFinderClass.cpp just in 1 file (main.cpp)
PS: I get the error in every definition in WayFinderClass.cpp

Comment: You shouldn't include a cpp file anywhere, only the h files.

Comment: @user3520616 So, you do include the cpp file? Have you included it in the compile command too?

Comment: @user2079303 Good call.  That would do it.

Comment: Thanks guys :)
After I included the .h file it works fine :)
Crazy because in another project it worked fine if I included the .cpp files in the main.cpp too...

Comment: @user2079303 Make sure you add your comments as an answer so that the OP can accept it.

Comment: @user3520616, Including a .cpp file in main.cpp would not cause errors if those .cpp files are not compiled themselves (not included in the compile command). Even though it might work in that case, you shouldn't do that. I've added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not include source files (.cpp). Include headers instead.

Your problem was probably caused by including the source file in main.cpp as you said and then compiling it separately as well. In that case, functions defined in `WayFinderClass.cpp` would be defined again in main due to the inclusion and you can't have more than one definition for a function.